# Selecting property of anonymous type using LINQ throws exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

My Linq query (i want to get list of items sorted by number of orders)

```
var x = context.Items.Include("Item_qualities").Join(
               context.Orders,
               i => i.Id,
               o => o.Item_id,
               (i, o) => new { i, o }
               )
               .GroupBy(e => new { e.i })
               .Select(w => new { w.Key.i, c = w.Count() })
               .OrderByDescending(y => y.c)
               .ToList().Select(u=>u.i);
```

Last part `Select(u=>u.i)` throws exception

> The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted,
>   except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

Comment: Look at the text of the exception. What is it trying to tell you?

Comment: An anonymous type must have variable names : { w.Key.i, c = w.Count() }

Comment: @CoryNelson: Text of the exception says that these types cannot be compared. But my u.i is not text, ntext, or image data type.

Comment: Is `context` an Entity Framework context?

Answer (score 0):

That error is pretty clear:

The text data type, which is deprecated as of SQL Server 2005, is not suitable for comparison so it is not possible to do sorting on it. The same goes for *image* data type. Read [this](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-306.aspx) for more details. In other words the database engine cannot do the sorting based on the column you have specified.

Comment: `w.Key.i` it is not text, it is Items type

Comment: The type in your c# code does not Metter. It is the type of the table on the sql server that needs to be fixed

Comment: @ScottChamberlain yes sorry I overlooked that the sorting will be executed at the db level.